# null pointer when query database

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i am searching for a number in my database and weather it exists in it or not and return a boolean but the query always gives me a null pointer exception when it is run

query

```
public boolean getPhone(String where){
    Cursor cur = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER},PHONE_NUMBER + "='" + where + "'",null,null,null,null); //fails here at the query
        Log.v("Cursor", cur.toString());
        String test = null;
        if(cur.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                test = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_NUMBER));
                Log.v("ContactDB", test);
            }while(cur.moveToNext());
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

implementation

```
        ContactDB db = new ContactDB(arg0);
        boolean dbNumber = db.getPhone(from);//searchNumber(arg0,from);
        if(dbNumber == true){
             //if number exists do stuff
        }else{
             //if number does not exist do other stuff
        }
```

it always fails at the query

```
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.app.notifyme.SmsReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at com.app.notifyme.ContactDB.getPhone(ContactDB.java:87)
03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at com.app.notifyme.SmsReciever.onReceive(SmsReciever.java:55)
```

03-16 11:57:06.522: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)

Comment: Where is line 87 in ContactDB.java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must open the database:

```
ContactDB db = new ContactDB(arg0);
db.open();
```

or it will throw NPEs. Don't forget to `close` it once you don't need it anymore.

Comment: but the method getPhone is in the database class so it should not need to be opened right?

*edit
oh nevermind i just noticed i didnt open it when i called the getPhone method

Answer (score 0):

Try changing up your `db.query( ... )` line:

```
Cursor cur = db.query(
  DATABASE_TABLE,
  new String [] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER},
  PHONE_NUMBER + " = " + theNumber,
  null, null, null, null, null);
```

As per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), your `selection` argument should not contain the `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: here where is a String which is passed as a parameter in the following method getPhone(String where).

Answer (score 0):

the db needs to be opened. Also try executing the sql query using the rawquery(query,selectionargs) method.